# amazon ec2 linux - why docker installation is getting failed in ec2 isntalce

Tags: linux, docker, amazon-ec2

How to enable extras in amazon linux ec2 instance.

I am getting below error:

```
 sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker Installing docker Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid 26210. Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...   The other application is: yum
    Memory : 277 M RSS (494 MB VSZ)
    Started: Sat Mar  7 18:58:52 2020 - 00:08 ago
    State  : Running, pid: 26210 Cleaning repos: amzn2-core amzn2extra-docker amzn2extra-nginx1.12 docker-ce-stable epel jenkins mongodb-org-4.0 30 metadata files removed 14 sqlite files removed 0 metadata files removed Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd amzn2-core                                     | 2.4 kB  00:00:00 amzn2extra-docker                                   | 1.8 kB  00:00:00 amzn2extra-nginx1.12                                | 1.3 kB  00:00:00 docker-ce-stable                                    | 3.5 kB  00:00:00 epel/x86_64/metalink                                | 8.5 kB  00:00:00 epel                                                | 5.3 kB  00:00:00 jenkins                                             | 2.9 kB  00:00:00 mongodb-org-4.0                                     | 2.5 kB  00:00:00 (1/13): amzn2-core/2/x86_64/group_gz                | 2.5 kB  00:00:00 (2/13): amzn2-core/2/x86_64/updateinfo              | 191 kB  00:00:00 (3/13): amzn2extra-docker/2/x86_64/updateinfo       |   69 B  00:00:00 (4/13): amzn2extra-docker/2/x86_64/primary_db       |  59 kB  00:00:00 (5/13): amzn2extra-nginx1.12/2/x86_64/primary_db    |  23 kB  00:00:00 (6/13): docker-ce-stable/x86_64/updateinfo          |   55 B  00:00:00 (7/13): docker-ce-stable/x86_64/primary_db          |  40 kB  00:00:00 (8/13): epel/x86_64/group_gz                        |  90 kB  00:00:00 (9/13): amzn2-core/2/x86_64/primary_db              |  38 MB  00:00:00 (10/13): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                     | 1.0 MB  00:00:00 (11/13): epel/x86_64/primary_db                     | 6.7 MB  00:00:00 (12/13): mongodb-org-4.0/primary_db                 |  85 kB  00:00:00 (13/13): jenkins/primary_db                         | 142 kB  00:00:01 196 packages excluded due to repository priority protections Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package docker.x86_64 0:18.09.9ce-2.amzn2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: runc = 1.0.0 for package: docker-18.09.9ce-2.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: containerd = 1.2.6 for package: docker-18.09.9ce-2.amzn2.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package containerd.io.x86_64 0:1.2.13-3.1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 for package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest Installation failed. Check that you have permissions to install.
```

[image]

Comment: I will recommend to use aws ECS optimized AMI, that is designed for Doker. You can use that AMI as in EC2 as well. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html